# The effect of hydrogen peroxide on yeast

Tags: sanitation, sanitizer, disinfecting

I did search, but didn't get any proper answer.
I have access to *bleach* and ***hydrogen peroxide (H2O2) and silver (Ag) ions*** (no star-san nor Iodophor).

I need to go with a no-rinse sanitizer.
I've heard hydrogen peroxide can be a good choice. But the question is that the producer claims it can be effective up to several days, so if I dilute it in water and disinfect my carboy and stuff without rinsing, isn't it gonna ruin my yeast?

BTW, I can't wait for hours for the solution to break down completely.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

Probably no problem. Chemical sanitizers will react with / be neutralized by all the organic material in the wort, leaving the yeast undamaged. But that doesn't necessarily mean you'll want the end result of that reaction in your beer.

tl;dr

Bleach is effective, and can work very quickly in a high concentrations*, but you'll want to rinse every bit of it away because chlorine-containing compounds can taste really bad.

Peroxides tend not to cause flavor problems because peroxides are naturally occurring compounds, but there are some other issues.

It seems that [hydrogen peroxide without silver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_peroxide#Disinfectant) isn't very good against spores, so it would be similar to boiling (better or worse? IDK), unless you crank up the concentration*.

Hydrogen peroxide with silver seems to be [more effective](http://www.chemtexlimited.com/oxidizing-biocide.html) and used in the food industry, but [rinsing](http://www.silverperoxide.com/Brochure%20silver-%20peroxide.pdf) is again recommended because you don't really want to [ingest silver nitrate](http://www.cdc.gov/niosh/ipcsneng/neng1116.html).

Peracetic acid is very popular, and effective at a safe & sane 0.2%, if you can get it.

If you can't get it, it will apparently form by mixing [vinegar and hydrogen peroxide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peracetic_acid). I'm not sure if the reaction carries any risks, or what concentration you'll get. But I can say that if you throw a bottle cap in it, and the metal starts to dissolve in 10 minutes or so, you're in the ball park**.

*It will also attack metal/flesh and/or explode and/or give off hydrogen when used this way.
**Don't do this without know some chemistry.

Comment: What is the correct concentration for H2O2?
The product I have is 7%. How should dilute it?

Comment: I'm used to 3% H2O2 as an over the counter antiseptic. But according to wikipedia 6% is commonly available. The same article also says 10-30% is need for effective spore killing (sterilization), but at this concentration it starts to get a little dangerous.

Comment: I have personal experience with 27% peroxide, wear your safety gear.  If even a slight residue gets on my skin it will burn and turn the skin white.  But it does kill a lot and it will also break down very quickly to just water and oxygen when exposed to UV light (hence the reason why most peroxide bottles are dark plastic).